# Int value becoming larger when sent to method

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

**SOLUTION:**

Simply separating the method call
     Tile *tile = [[Tile alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
into two separate lines such as:
     Tile *tile = [Tile alloc];
     [tile initWithX:x Y:y];
caused the method to stop receiving the ints as memory pointers. I'm baffled as to why this occurred but it fixed the problems. Any explanations as to why this happened would be appreciated. Thanks to all for the help!

**ORIGINAL POST:**

This is a bit of a weird question as I've run into this problem while doing a tutorial at: http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2010/09/23/cocos2d-game-tutorial-building-a-slide-image-game/.

The program I have typed out works except for the switching of tiles, and I have looked in the XCode debugger and it seems that my x and y values for the Tile class are being set way to absurdly high values. The weird thing is, when the values are passed to the method (initWithX:Y:) from the original method (initWithSize:imgSize:) they are what they should be, but when they arrive at the method they are huge (for example: in one instance an x passed as '1' becomes '1065353216' when it arrives at the method.)

I have a feeling that it may be pointing to the memory location of the passed int, but I don't see any reason why it should be in my code. See below.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)aSize imgSize:(int)aImgValue {
self = [super init];
imgValue = aImgValue;
size = aSize;
OutBorderTile = [[Tile alloc] initWithX:-1 Y:-1];
content = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size.height];

readyToRemoveTiles = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:50];

for(int y = 0; y < size.height; y++) {
    NSMutableArray *rowContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size.width];
    for (int x = 0; x < size.width; x++) {
        Tile *tile = [[Tile alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
        [rowContent addObject:tile];
        [readyToRemoveTiles addObject:tile];
        [tile release];
    }
    [content addObject:rowContent];
    [content retain];
}
[readyToRemoveTiles retain];
return self;
}

-(id)initWithX:(int)posX Y:(int)posY {
self = [super init];
x = posX;
y = posY;
return self;
}
```

Everything should be the same as in the linked tutorial, but I can't see anybody else complaining of the same problem.

I have also noted that if I go into the debugger and manually change the posX and posY values in the initWithX method that the tile switching code works, so my problem definitely lies with the really large int values forming in that method.

**Edit for Jim:** Hopefully this shows a more complete picture of the layout I have for the Tile object.

```
@interface Tile : NSObject {
int x, y, value;
CCSprite *sprite;
}

@property(nonatomic, readonly) int x, y;
@property(nonatomic) int value;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *sprite;

@end

@implementation Tile

@synthesize x, y, value, sprite;

// Code is logged in below. 
-(id)initWithX:(int)posX Y:(int)posY {
self = [super init];
x = posX;
y = posY;
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Post the code where you declare the `x` and `y` instance variables and the code where you log the values.

Comment: if you clean and rebuild, is there any compiler warning on `[[Tile alloc] initWithX:x Y:y]` line?

Comment: Jim: I've edited the above post to show the initialization of the instance variables and tried to show how the code is logged. If you look at the first example you can see how I call the -(id)initWithX:Y: method.

hamstergene: I cleaned and rebuilt, but I didn't get a compiler warning.

Comment: Okay, I got it. It's weird but when I made 
Tile *tile = [[Tile alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
into: 

Tile *tile = [Tile alloc];
[tile initWithX:x Y:y];

The program started to receive the int values properly and not as the pointers it was seeing before. 

Any explanations as to why nesting the alloc and the init together would cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, the `x` and/or `y` value are being assigned to a pointer. One thing I would check is to make sure you aren't declaring your ints as pointers to ints. I.e. `int *x`, etc.

Comment: That's exactly what was happening, but I'm not too sure why putting my alloc and my initialization statement in the same line caused it to happen.